# Azure VM image does not have Source Blob URI

Tags: azure-rm-template

After following the instructions for creating a managed image in Azure, I'm trying to create a VM from the managed image inside the ARM template.  The ARM template requires a source blob URI which should be listed on the VM image page within the Azure portal, but it's blank (see screen shot below).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/capture-image-resource

Did I miss a step somewhere?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, to create a vm from the managed disk image you need its resource id, not its uri (because it doesnt have one). Here's an ARM Template bit to create a VM from the managed disk image:

```
"storageProfile": {
    "imageReference": {
        "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/images', concat(parameters('vmPrefix'), '-gateway-osImage'))]"
    },
    "osDisk": {
        "name": "[concat(parameters('vmPrefix'), '-gateway-os-vhd')]",
        "createOption": "FromImage"
    }
},
```